# How do you use Interfaces with the Factory Pattern in Domain-Driven Design?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, domain-driven-design, factory, domain-object

Does it make sense to use interfaces for your domain object factories by default, or should interfaces be reserved for the factory classes only when you need them?

```
public IUserFactory
{
    User CreateNewUser();
}

public UserFactory : IUserFactory
{
    public User CreateNewUser()
    {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why...? What is the benefit to always doing this?

Comment: Though your example is in C#, there's no reason why we can't ask this design question in Java.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to leave out java folks, or anyone for that matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a translation of the same problem into Java.

Original example

```
public interface UserFactoryIF
{
   User createNewUser();
}
```

Then the implementation of the Factory

```
public class UserFactory implements UserFactoryIF
{
     public User createNewUser()
     {
         // whatever special logic it takes to make a User
         // below is simplification
         return new User();
     }
}
```

I don't see any special benefit to defining an interface for the factory, since you're defining a single interface for a centralized producer. Typically I find that I need to produce many different implementations of the same kind of product, and my factory needs to consume many different kinds of parameters. That is, we might have:

```
public interface User
{
    public String getName();
    public long getId();
    public long getUUID();
    // more biz methods on the User
}
```

The factory would look like this:

```
public class UserFactory {

    public static User createUserFrom(Person person) {
        // ...
        return new UserImpl( ... );
    }

    public static user createUserFrom(AmazonUser amazonUser) {
         // ... special logic for AmazonWS user
        return new UserImpl( ... );          
    }

    private static class UserImpl implements User {
       // encapsulated impl with validation semantics to
       // insure no one else in the production code can impl
       // this naively with side effects
    }
}
```

Hope this gets the point across.

Answer (score 7):

In your given example, I don't even see why you need to go Factory.

> The essence of the Factory Pattern is
>   to "Define an interface for creating
>   an object, but let the subclasses
>   decide which class to instantiate. The
>   Factory method lets a class defer
>   instantiation to subclasses." - Wikipedia

Do you have a different type of Users, or User is itself a type of something. May be you didn't elaborate the thing clearly. We usually use *interface* in **abstract factory method pattern**, where we need to deal with multiple families of related objects.

NOTE: Don't forget, patterns are there to help us, it doesn't mean that we must use them because they are available, whether we need them or not.

Answer (score 5):

Not everything has to have an interface; if you have a single implementation of something, and no reason to have any other I can't see why define an interface.

Comment: Also the collection of method signatures on a class counts an interface, which is independent of whether you're implementing a Java/C# interface.

Answer (score 2):

Creating the factory off an interface allows it much easier to test them with mock classes, as well as making it simpler to use IoC applications, so whilst I may not necessarily need them for the application functionality, I generally build and call most classes through interfaces.

If you are not considering Unit Tests or IoC patterns (religious opinions aside), I probably wouldn't bother.

I find the biggest pain with using them, in Visual Studio at least, is that 'Go To Definition' on a property or function jumps to the Interface definition, not the class definition.

Comment: Can't you create mock objects from non interface based classes using moq (for example)?

Comment: True, but if you are creating your own as you need finer control over functionality, it's always nicer to do them through an interface

Answer (score 2):

Two things:  (1) I'd wait until I needed (or saw a looming need) an alternative implementation before I'd create the interface and (2) interfaces almost always make unit testing easier, especially with mocking, so I frequently come up with a need for an interface right away.